# extracting value from a json response unix

Tags: unix

I have a JSON response stored in a variable

```
{
    "StepIds": [
        "s-12AB34Cdb"
    ]
}
```

how to I extract a value using sed on unix and store it into a variable

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `sed`. You can use the `jq` command-line JSON parser:

```
ID=$(echo $VAR | jq -r '.StepIds[0]')
echo $ID
```

Output:

```
s-12AB34Cdb
```